# Existing of an automorphism in Noether normalization lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Lemma.
Let
$D$
be a domain and let
$f
\in
D
[
x_1
, \cdots ,x_n
]$
. Let
$N \geq1$
be an integer that
bounds all the exponents of the variables occurring in the terms of
$f$
. Let $\phi$
be the
$D$-automorphism of
$D
[
x_1
, \cdots ,x_n
]$
such that
$x_i \rightarrow x_i+x^{N^i}_n$
for
$i < n$
and such that
$x_n$
maps
to itself. Then the image of
$f$
under
is a polynomial whose highest degree term involving
$x_n$
has the form
$cx^m_n$
, where
$c$
is a nonzero element of
$D$
.

Can you explaine why such $\phi$ exists? Is it necessary that $\phi$ preserves the addition and multiplication on $D$?

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the universal property of the polynomial ring that $\phi:D[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to D[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is defined. Indeed, it is enough to specify where the variables are mapped if you require that $\phi$ is a homomorphism of $D$-algebras, which is done here implicitly. This means that not only addition and multiplication on $D$ are preserved, in fact addition and multiplication of the entire ring are preserved and $\phi$ is also $D$-linear. If this is required, then a choice of images for the $x_i$ already dictates the image of any polynomial in the $x_i$ under $\phi$.

Now if $\phi$ has an inverse, it must certainly map $\psi(x_n)=x_n$. On the other hand, we must have $x_i=\psi(x_i+x_n^{N^i})=\psi(x_i)+\psi(x_n)^{N^i}=\psi(x_i)+x_n^{N^i}$. Defining $\psi(x_i):=x_i-x_n^{N^i}$ does the trick!